# How can I make a Div that stays on its position?

Tags: jquery, css, html

I 'm having a hard time how to properly describe what i'm asking but here's the best example from [boingboing.net](http://www.boingboing.net/). Look at the sidebar then scroll down to the bottom. Notice how the last widget(i dont know what it is, sorry.) or Advertise stays at its place when the user scrolls down? It also stops when reaching the bottom. how am i gonna do that?

i know the css attributes, `position:fixed;` but i guess that method is different from boingboing.net. need help on this matter. any help? Thank you very much!

Comment: Have a look at [this tutorial](http://andrewhenderson.me/tutorial/jquery-sticky-sidebar/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bind an event on scroll of `window`, and set the `position` of target div, based on the `scrolltop` of `window`.

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
   if($(this).scrollTop() >= 500){
      $('targetdiv').css('position','fixed');
   }
   else {
      $('targetdiv').css('position','relative');  // or any other position
   }
});
```

or better you can add a `class` on particular top of `window` which has `position:fixed`

Comment: may i ask what is this line for?

if($(this).scrollTop >= 500)

Comment: Yes, you can ask ;). Jokes apart.. `$(this)` refers to `window` `object` to which we binded the `scroll` event. `scrollTop()` is a function which gives the top of the `window`

Comment: thanks Jashwant, im using wordpress right now. any idea where should i paste your codes? when i pasted that in my functions.php file, there's an error.

Comment: In wp, you cannot use,`$` , use `jQuery` instead.

Comment: Shouldn't the format for the css properties be either:
`css({'position':'fixed'})` or
`css('position','fixed')`
The latter, from my limited understand, is used for a single pair of key/value and the former for multiple.

Comment: @Marcus, funny this ans got 4 upvotes but no one noticed the typo. You are right. fixed it.

Comment: I noticed it only when I tried it :D Thanks for the solution I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You need an [affixation plugin](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#affix). You should be able to download the one from [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/customize.html) by untoggling everything except that plugin.

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<img src=//ph.artsinn.de alt>
<div>
    <p>A short line of text, for better interpretation.</p>
    <p>Followed by another line, filled with letter and words</p> 
</div>

<img src=//ph.artsinn.de/240x160/666?text=scroll%20down alt id=obj>

<img src=//ph.artsinn.de alt>
<img src=//ph.artsinn.de alt>
<img src=//ph.artsinn.de alt>
<img src=//ph.artsinn.de alt>
```

**CSS**

```
/* not needed */
html,body{height:200%}
img {display:block}
```

**JS**

```
$(function() { 
    $window = $(window),
    $sidebar = $("#obj"),
    sidebarTop = $sidebar.position().top,
    $sidebar.css('position', 'fixed');

    $window.scroll(function(e) {
        scrollTop = $window.scrollTop(),
        topPosition = Math.max(0, sidebarTop - scrollTop),
        $sidebar.css('top', topPosition);
    });
});
```

---

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ARTsinn/SuEAg/)**